# Can't create Foreign key on mysql database

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm cannot create any foreign key in my mysql database. I used foreign key before, but recently I had to reformat and reinstall everything, and after a restored the mysql server, the foreign keys aren't working anymore.

I tried to create the simple tables bellow:

```
create table `order` (
    order_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    customer varchar(100)
);

create table `order_item` (
    order_item_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    order_id int not null,
    product varchar(100),
    foreign key (order_id) references `order`
);
```

The order tables is created successfully, but when i try to create the order_item table, i get the message `Error Code: 1005. Can't create table` mydb`.`order_item `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`. I've checked my code multiple times, and I'm not able to find a error. Do someone knows what could be wrong?

I'm using XAMPP to install and start both apache and mysql.

---

Edit:
@LV98 's answer solved the error, but when i added a second Foreign key, got the same message:

```
create table `order` (
    order_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    customer varchar(100)
);

create table product (
    product_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100)
);

create table `order_item` (
    order_item_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    order_id int not null,
    product_id int not null,
    product varchar(100),
    foreign key (order_id) references `order`(order_id),
    foreign key (product_id) references product (product_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reference a column.

```
foreign key (order_id) references `order`(order_id)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, but when I added a second foreign key I got the same error. I will edit the question to post that.

Comment: @Marlon Try to `product (product_id)` remove the space in between.

Comment: Already tried that, but it didn't work. I also remove the whitespace between 'foreign key' and the field: `foreign key(order_id)`

Comment: @Marlon Your query works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d36104 have you got anything else around your code, above or below?

Comment: I clicked the link you sent, but when I run it, it shows nothing, event if I add a select ... after. And no, I've nothing else on my code. I'm even selecting each create table statement and executing it separately. Could it be something related to mysql version, since its bundled with XAMPP?:

Comment: Click `build schema` instead of run  Where are you running the query? Are you using Workbench?